# iOS tableView pagination

Tags: ios, uitableview, rss, pagination

I have a tableView that shows a list of rss feeds in it's cells, some times the list can get to long so I need to show like 15 items then have a bottom cell with load more,
Once selected show next 15 items

I have search a lot on how to achieve this with out success

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is slicing the RSS feed to just 10-20 articles enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a code to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

that manages each cell content with clauses(for example if row mod 15 = 0, then do not populate cell with data).

and a code to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

that manages what to do when a certain cell is clicked. For example load more RSS entries(add them to NSMutableArray/Dictionary) and then reload entire table and position to a certain cell. Of course, you will have to modify other methods too, make a variable table size, etc.